# Can I use Guzzle by itself to develop an application?

Tags: guzzle

I want to know whether I can use Guzzle alone to develop an entire application. Or is it only a component that you stick to an actual framework like Yii.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guzzle is simply a library for making HTTP calls. You would use it as part of a project to pull/push data to other sources